# Is the way I am swapping the ordering of this vector wrong?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, swap

I find myself lost and seeking the guidance from the internet!

I have a struct as follows:

```
struct Company {
    string name;
    string language;
    int pay;
    int age;
```

This struct I have stored in a '**class CompanyManager**' that has a '**vector >Company>**'.

```
class CompanyManager {
    vector<Company> companyVector;
}
```

Now the issue I have is that I want to randomize the order of the Company structs within the vector.

Here is my attempt with the help of google.

```
    int size = this->companyVector.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
       int j = i + rand() % (size - i);
       swap(this->companyVector[i], this->companyVector[j]);
    }
```

I think I'm doing something wrong here but I'm not sure exactly what. Would this swap the contents of my structs, because that's what seems to be happening in my program.

Just to be clear, I am trying to swap the order of the Company vector.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use the standard algorithm `std::shuffle()` to shuffle the vector?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What's the difference between 'swapping the contents of elements of a vector' and 'swapping the order of (elements of) a vector'...?

Comment: I don't know if my compiler is old/new but I cannot seem to access std::shuffle(). I get the warning/error: "no instance of function template "std::shuffle" matches the argument list C/C++(304)". That is why I resorted to a more manual approach. std::random_shuffle doesn't exist in my version of C++ either.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, if you're not using the standard library algorithm, you're doing it wrong. <g>

Answer (score 0):

There is already an algorithm that exactly does what you want in the stl, `std::random_shuffle`:

```cpp
std::random_shuffle(this->companyVector.begin(), this->companyVector.end());
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Edit: if you are using C++17, you should use `std::shuffle`, since `std::random_shuffle` has been deprecated in 14 (see the comments)

Comment: `std::random_shuffle()` was deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17.   There is now `std::shuffle()`.

Comment: I've modified the post accordingly :)